# NullPointerException when saving AbstractTableModel to file

Tags: java, swing, exception

I have the following code which returns a NullPointerException:

```
    private void misaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       

      if(fc.showSaveDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
    try {
        File file = new File(fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(m);
        oos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        jDialog7.setVisible(true);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

   }
 }
}
```

where variable m is declared as a field of my JFrame.
Im a bit of a noob at java and I cant quite pinpoint the source of this exception, my best guess is that variable m is null for some reason. Calling getElementAt for m in the try catch clause returns correctly so m is not null? 
This is the declaration of m as a field:

```
private CarteDeTelefon m = new CarteDeTelefon();
```

This code:

```
fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()
```

returns the path correctly, so my question is, what are the possible causes for this exception here?

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel.paintRegion(SynthLookAndFeel.java:371)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel.update(SynthLookAndFeel.java:335)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthViewportUI.update(SynthViewportUI.java:167)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:780)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1056)
at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:728)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:889)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1065)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5210)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1579)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1502)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1272)
at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5158)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4969)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:831)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:814)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:814)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:789)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:738)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(RepaintManager.java:64)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1732)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Show us the stack trace. Print out `m`'s value to make sure it's not null.

Comment: Turns out m is not null. Added the stack trace.